# RISC-V disassembled program dump different from the cycle-accurate emulator output?

Tags: riscv

Good day!

I have a problem with running the RISC-V rocket-chip cycle-accurate emulator for the `dummy_rocc_test.c` program that I compile, located in the rocket-chip repository (riscv-tools/riscv-isa-sim/dummy_rocc).

I will explain my steps below and place the problem afterwards. The steps I'm taking:

1. `git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip.git`
2. `git submodule update --init --recursive` in the `rocket-chip`, `rocket-chip/riscv-tools` directories
3. `export RISCV=[a folder called riscv-toolchain]`
4. `export PATH=[...]/riscv-toolchain/bin:$PATH`
5. `. rocket-chip/riscv-tools/build.sh` (without running `build-rv32im.sh` afterwards)
6. `make CONFIG=RoccExampleConfig` in the `rocket-chip/emulator` directory
7. `cd rocket-chip/riscv-tools/riscv-isa-sim/dummy_rocc`
8. `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc dummy_rocc_test.c -o dummy_rocc_test.out`
9. (while in the `dummy_rocc` folder)
   `rocket-chip/emulator/emulator-TestHarness-RoccExampleConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=10000 +verbose pk dummy_rocc_test.out 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | spike-dasm > dummy_rocc_test.log`
10. `riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump --disassemble-all dummy_rocc_test.out > dummy_rocc_test.dump`

The output of `dummy_rocc_test.log` file (first 25 lines, full text [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/drgprj/e7c5d6b653abf86e5605af3a10b9211b/raw/1221baaa010c9a0fca8013dd68f6d262c68d7bbc/dummy_rocc_test.log)):

```
C0:          0 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:          1 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:          2 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:          3 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:          4 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:          5 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:          6 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:          7 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:          8 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:          9 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         10 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         11 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         12 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         13 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         14 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         15 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         16 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         17 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         18 [0] pc=[b90caeae11] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r19=0000000000000000] R[r 4=918250ce690efa03] inst=[024983dc] unknown
C0:         19 [0] pc=[0000001000] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r13=0000000000000000] R[r 0=918250ce690efa03] inst=[0e06b783] ld      a5, 224(a3)
C0:         20 [0] pc=[0000001002] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r 0=0000000000000000] R[r 0=918250ce690efa03] inst=[00006db7] lui     s11, 0x6
C0:         21 [0] pc=[0000001002] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r 0=0000000000000000] R[r 0=918250ce690efa03] inst=[00006db7] lui     s11, 0x6
C0:         22 [0] pc=[0000001002] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r 0=0000000000000000] R[r 0=918250ce690efa03] inst=[00006db7] lui     s11, 0x6
C0:         23 [0] pc=[0000001002] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r 0=0000000000000000] R[r 0=918250ce690efa03] inst=[00006db7] lui     s11, 0x6
C0:         24 [0] pc=[0000001002] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r 0=0000000000000000] R[r 0=918250ce690efa03] inst=[00006db7] lui     s11, 0x6
C0:         25 [0] pc=[0000001002] W[r 0=0000000000000000][0] R[r 0=0000000000000000] R[r 0=918250ce690efa03] inst=[00006db7] lui     s11, 0x6
...
```

The output of `dummy_rocc_test.dump` (first 35 lines, full text [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/drgprj/e7c5d6b653abf86e5605af3a10b9211b/raw/1221baaa010c9a0fca8013dd68f6d262c68d7bbc/dummy_rocc_test.dump))

```
dummy_rocc_test.out:     file format elf64-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000010000 <_ftext>:
   10000:   00008197            auipc   gp,0x8
   10004:   d8018193            addi    gp,gp,-640 # 17d80 <_gp>
   10008:   00007297            auipc   t0,0x7
   1000c:   5d028293            addi    t0,t0,1488 # 175d8 <_PathLocale>
   10010:   00007317            auipc   t1,0x7
   10014:   67030313            addi    t1,t1,1648 # 17680 <_end>
   10018:   0002b023            sd  zero,0(t0)
   1001c:   00828293            addi    t0,t0,8
   10020:   fe62ece3            bltu    t0,t1,10018 <_ftext+0x18>
   10024:   00000517            auipc   a0,0x0
   10028:   2f050513            addi    a0,a0,752 # 10314 <__libc_fini_array>
   1002c:   2a4000ef            jal 102d0 <atexit>
   10030:   3c0000ef            jal 103f0 <__libc_init_array>
   10034:   00012503            lw  a0,0(sp)
   10038:   00810593            addi    a1,sp,8
   1003c:   00000613            li  a2,0
   10040:   124000ef            jal 10164 <main>
   10044:   2a00006f            j   102e4 <exit>

0000000000010048 <_fini>:
   10048:   00008067            ret

000000000001004c <deregister_tm_clones>:
   1004c:   00017537            lui a0,0x17
   10050:   000177b7            lui a5,0x17
   10054:   57850713            addi    a4,a0,1400 # 17578 <__TMC_END__>
   10058:   57f78793            addi    a5,a5,1407 # 1757f <__TMC_END__+0x7>
   1005c:   40e787b3            sub a5,a5,a4
...
```

My main problem is that I cannot make the emulator output me a `SUCCESS!` with a correct number of cycles for the compiled program `dummy_rocc_test.c`. The same program runs fine with `spike pk`. The output from the emulator `dummy_rocc_test.log` shows that there's no instruction from the disassembled program file `dummy_rocc_test.dump` is being executed; so the program itself isn't being executed by the emulator.

I understand the emulator starts with randomized values in its registers, that's explains the first value in `pc`. Afterwards, it sets at `[0000001000]` which, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it's the same `0x10000` address from where programs start to execute if run with a proxy kernel (where the first instruction in `dummy_rocc_test.dump` should be).

I do believe that `pc` should start first with a value of `0x200`/`pc=[0000000200]` first though, to start the proxy kernel (`0x200` being the address of choice for starting bare-metal programs by RISC-V). Even if I give a bigger number for `+maxcycles` in step 9, `pc` just loops through the same addresses, never going through `[0000001000]` again or though `[0000000200]` and outputting the same `FAILED!` in the end because the program apparently didn't execute in time.

I would like to understand where am I wrong in the thinking I'm doing or in the steps I'm taking. Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is the command you are giving the cycle accurate emulator?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late answer. I feel like I've already mentioned that in the original post, though. In step 9: `rocket-chip/emulator/emulator-TestHarness-RoccExampleConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=10000 +verbose pk dummy_rocc_test.out 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | spike-dasm > dummy_rocc_test.log`.